# JavaScript/PHP Regular Expression

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to match first names and Lastname with something like this.

```
$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z\-]{3,30} +[a-zA-Z]+/';
```

This works great, except when I have a first name like this `Mélissa Smith`

My match becomes `Lissa Smith`

How do I match for all special characters like `é`

Comment: And how about names like this one (dutch example): `Jeroen van den Hoogen`? Should you program be able to handle these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript, you can use a unicode char range instead of A-Za-z:

```
"Mélissa Smith".match(  /[\u80-\uffff]{3,30} +[\u80-\uffff]+/  )
```

equals: ["Mélissa Smith"]

Comment: This was matching a bit too much but was exactly the right direction at least for JavaScript.

Ended up using 
    match(/[\u80-\uffff]+/gi

Answer (score 0):

Put the regex into Unicode mode with the `/u` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and use an appropriate [Unicode character class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) instead of hardcoding just latin letters:

```
$pattern = '/^(\pL|-){3,30}\s+\pL+$/u';
```

I also anchored the pattern between `^` and `$` because otherwise it could end up matching things you didn't intend it to.

You have to keep in mind that when you do this, the input (as well as the pattern itself) *must* be encoded in UTF-8.

However, it has to be said that naively parsing names like this is not going to give you very good results. People's full names are way too involved for something this simple to work across the board.

Comment: This answer is acceptable for PHP, but javascript does not support unicode character classes, only escapes such as "\uFFFF". OP didn't really specify, though.

Comment: @dequis: I have no idea why the question is tagged JS, but the code given is definitely PHP. That's why I only addressed that language.

Comment: I'm actually using both JavaScript and PHP to parse out First and Last Names in different parts of my application.  If I had to could use only one.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the POSIX expression [:alpha:] instead of [a-zA-Z-] to catch the characters.  [:alpha:] will catch equivalent characters such as accents.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: The POSIX regular expression engine is deprecated in PHP since 5.3, and might be removed in the future.